# Why don't need install SSL certificate when browser access a http webpage with https APIs

Tags: ssl, https

I am studying SSL. The certificate thing confuses me a lot. Assume that there is a web page http://foo.com, it uses some https APIs(like login) on this page. When browser access this page, It should have https request. But Browser can access it without installing certificate. just like accessing a normal http webpage.

How this happened?

I mean there are https requests when load this http page, the browser should establish SSL connection with server and check certificate from server just like accessing https webpage.  But we don't install any certificate for http://foo.com, browser can access it normally.

Answer (score 2):

Browsers have a number of top-level certificates pre-installed from common/popular certificate authorities.  During the handshake, the server sends its certificate to the browser, which decides whether to actually verify the certificate or not, and if so then verify that the certificate was signed by one of the known authorities it already has a certificate for.  Most of the time, this is sufficient.  But sometimes a server uses an uncommon/custom certificate authority that the browser does not know about, so that authority's certificate has to be installed into the browser first.

Comment: Thanks you, It's very helpful. 
Do you know how mitm(man-in-the-middle) proxy fools the browser with its certificate ? I used mitm proxy to debug https. I confuse that there is no "https://" domain name in mitm proxy's certificate  why browser allow it to access without a warrnning ?

Comment: That falls under the "custom certificate must be installed first" category.  For example, look at Fiddler.  It dynamically generates a custom certificate each time it is run, and a web browser prompts the user about an unknown/untrusted certificate that the user must accept before the browser will allow the connection to proceed.

Comment: Thanks, That enlighten me. I hacked mitmproxy (a python mitm proxy), got how it works -- The proxy releases a Root CA which browser should install. then, just like you said: it dynamical  generates a custom certificate according to domain name. For example (https :// www.bar.com), It will make a certificate with subject name "*.bar.name" signed by its Root CA on the fly.
The browser trusts its Root CA, then trusts this certificated too. So nice can get this, Thank you again.